# What's the meaning of this source code of interface Collection in JAVA?

Tags: java, collections

In the interface Collection:

```
    default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(filter);
    boolean removed = false;
    final Iterator<E> each = iterator();
    while (each.hasNext()) {
        if (filter.test(each.next())) {
            each.remove();
            removed = true;
        }
    }
    return removed;
}
```

I am puzzled by the expression:

```
            if (filter.test(each.next())) {
                each.remove();
            }
```

Why the "each" is removed when "each.next" match the if condition?
I think the below is more reasonable:

```
            if (filter.test(each)) {
                each.remove();
            }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You need to call `each.next()` at some point, to move through the `Iterator`, and to get the value from the `Iterator`.  If you don't do it on that line, you'd need to add an extra line before it.

Comment: *"Why the "each" is removed when "each.next" match the if condition?"* - because `removeIf()` removes elements that match the given `Predicate`, i.e. for which condition is being evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from a misunderstanding of the `Iterator#remove()` method. Here's its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()):

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once per call to next().

So, it's not `each` that is being removed from the collection, but the latest element returned by the call to `each.next()` (but only if `filter.test(each.next())` returns `true`).

Here's some equivalent code but more "spread out" and some small name changes:

```java
default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> shouldRemove) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(shouldRemove);

  boolean wasModified = false;

  Iterator<E> iterator = this.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    E currentValue = iterator.next();
    if (shouldRemove.test(currentValue)) {
      iterator.remove(); // removes 'currentValue' from 'this'
      wasModified = true;
    }
  }

  return wasModified;
}
```

---

As for why `filter.test(each)` is wrong, that's because that would result in a compilation error due to mismatched types. The `test` methods expects an object of type `E`, but `each` is an `Iterator<E>`.